# Get registry key value and change accordingly from multiple PCs

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, registry

First thank you for this great site! I've learned lots of batch scripting from here, but finally got stuck. I was tasked to write a script that will go out and check a specific registry keyword and change the ones that are not correct, on all PCs on the network.

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F %%a in (C:\batchFiles\computers.txt) DO (
   FOR /F "tokens=3" %%b in (reg query "\\%%a\HKLM\SOFTWARE\some\any" /v "Forms Path") do set "var=%%b"
     if "%var%" == "\\server\folder\forms\path"
       echo %%a was correct
       pause
     if "%var%" NEQ "\\server\folder\forms\path"
       echo %%a was not correct
       pause      
)
```

My boss tasked me with this not to long ago and its a little above my head, so i'm trying to learn on the fly. I tried with %errorlevel% and couldn't get it to do what I wanted either.

I had all of my PC names listed in C:\batchFiles\computers.txt. The REG_SZ key from "Forms Path" is a folder located on a network drive. Right now it says that the syntax is incorrect. 
If you can understand what i'm trying to do, and have a better suggestion, I'm all ears! Oh and I'd like to output ALL of the results to a text file so I know which PCs were changed, which ones had it correct, and which ones the script couldn't reach.

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You enabled delayed environment variable expansion, but do not use it. `%var%` must be written as `!var!` to make use of delayed expansion as required here.

The syntax used on both `if` conditions is also not correct.

The registry query output by `reg.exe` on my computer running Windows XP is:

```
! REG.EXE VERSION 3.0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\some\any
    Forms Path  REG_SZ  \\server\folder\forms\path
```

There is first a blank line, next a line with version of `reg.exe`, one more blank line, a line with registry key and finally on fifth line the data of interest. Therefore I used in the batch code below `skip=4` to speed it up. However, the inner loop would produce the right result also without `skip=4` and therefore parsing all 5 lines.

Important is the last line. The inner loop separates by spaces. As the name of the registry value contains also a space character, the first two *tokens* are for `Forms` and `Path`. And the third token is `REG_SZ`.

The rest of the line after the spaces after `REG_SZ` is of real interest, but could contain also a space character. So I used in batch code below not `tokens=4`, but instead `tokens=3*` and ignored `%b` which holds `REG_SZ`. Instead `%c` is assigned to environment variable `var` resulting in getting really entire string value even if the string contains 1 or more spaces.

And the environment variable `var` is deleted before a new query on next computer is executed in case of a computer does not contain the registry value at all. The error message written by `reg.exe` to *stderr* is redirected to device `nul` for this case. The value of `var` would be unchanged from previous computer if not deleted before running the next query.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%a in (C:\batchFiles\computers.txt) do (
   set var=
   for /F "skip=4 tokens=3*" %%b in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "\\%%a\HKLM\SOFTWARE\some\any" /v "Forms Path" 2^>nul') do set "var=%%c"
   if "!var!" == "\\server\folder\forms\path" (
      echo %%a has correct value.
   ) else if "!var!" == "" (
      echo %%a does not have the value at all.
   ) else (
      echo %%a has wrong value.
   )
   pause
)
endlocal
```